# Notes 8.5.3: How to set reply defaults to 'reply' without history?

Tags: windows-7, lotus-notes

Is it possible to default the reply format to other than 'reply with history only'?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's not possible using Preferences (or Mail Preferences for Notes clients older than 8.5).

Long Answer: if you have the designer client you could modify the mail template to remove re-order the mail templates.